# External JavaScript and PHP to rotate through folder of images

Tags: php, javascript

I'm trying to use Javascript and PHP to read a folder of images and cycle through the images.
I got the idea and code from here: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/externalphp2.shtml

I'm not getting any errors even with Firebug up. But it's just not cycling through the images. It loads the first image that I set (userfiles/portfolio/0025.jpg). But doesn't ever move to another image.

The getimages.php is located in userfiles/portfolio along with my images.

Here's what I have:

On the page I want to display the images:

```
<script src="userfiles/portfolio/getimages.php"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var curimg=0
function rotateimages(){
document.getElementById("slideshow").setAttribute("src", "userfiles/portfolio/"+galleryarray[curimg])
curimg=(curimg<galleryarray.length-1)? curimg+1 : 0
}

window.onload=function(){
setInterval("rotateimages()", 1000)
}
</script>

<div id="portfoilo">
    <img id="slideshow" src="userfiles/portfolio/0025.jpg" />
</div>
```

and here is my getimages.php

```
 <?php
//PHP SCRIPT: getimages.php
Header("content-type: application/x-javascript");

//This function gets the file names of all images in the current directory
//and ouputs them as a JavaScript array
function returnimages($dirname=".") {
    $pattern="(\.jpg$)|(\.png$)|(\.jpeg$)|(\.gif$)"; //valid image extensions
    $files = array();
    $curimage=0;
    if($handle = opendir($dirname)) {
        while(false !== ($file = readdir($handle))){
            if(eregi($pattern, $file)){ //if this file is a valid image
            //Output it as a JavaScript array element
            echo 'galleryarray['.$curimage.']="'.$file .'";';
            $curimage++;
            }
        }

            closedir($handle);
        }
    return($files);
}

echo 'var galleryarray=new Array();'; //Define array in JavaScript
returnimages() //Output the array elements containing the image file names
?>
```

getimages.php was showing up blank when I ran it.  However now I'm getting:

```
<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-deprecated xe-scream' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for</th></tr>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Deprecated: Function eregi() is deprecated in J:\My Documents\Dropbox\www\ChiseledImages-Ras\userfiles\portfolio\getimages.php on line <i>13</i></th></tr>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
<tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0014</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>248760</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='J:\My Documents\Dropbox\www\ChiseledImages-Ras\userfiles\portfolio\getimages.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\getimages.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>2</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0015</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>249536</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>returnimages(  )</td><td title='J:\My Documents\Dropbox\www\ChiseledImages-Ras\userfiles\portfolio\getimages.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\getimages.php<b>:</b>26</td></tr>
</table></font>
```

Is eregi completely gone now? I know it was being deprecated after 5 and my WAMP version is running php 5.4.3.

Comment: What is the problem? Are you getting errors?

Comment: LOL. Guess it would help if I said what the problem was.  
I'm not getting any errors even with Firebug up.  It's just not cycling through the images.  It loads the first image that I set (userfiles/portfolio/0025.jpg).  But doesn't ever move to another image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a quick glance of your code, but you should probably change this:

```
setInterval("rotateimages()", 1000)
```

to this

```
setInterval(rotateimages, 1000);
```

This is because you're telling Javascript to run a specific function after 1 second. So you'll need to pass in something that is *callable* like a function reference or an anonymous function block. In your case, you're passing in a string which is not *callable*.

Comment: thanks for the quick response however I'm still getting the same result.

Comment: Try placing alerts in your code to see what is not firing. Also, you should edit your answer to include the content that your PHP script outputs.

Comment: I wasn't getting any output before.  Now I'm getting what is above.  I see the php error that eregi has been deprecated.  I'm assuming that since I'm on php 5.4.3 and eregi was deprecated after 5 that that is causing the issue?
Should I try it with stristr() instead?

Comment: k. now I'm cooking with gas.  I changed to stristr(). So now it's returning  var galleryarray=new Array();galleryarray[0]=".";

On the page that should display the images, it's at least trying to advanced, but obviously there's no images according to the array to advanced to.  I'm going to try to work this out and let you know if I can't get it.

Comment: You should be using `preg_match_all` with the case-insensitive modifier. Like this: `preg_match('/(\.jpg$)|(\.png$)|(\.jpeg$)|(\.gif$)/i', $file);`

Comment: In the context of your conditional, `if (preg_match('/(\.jpg$)|(\.png$)|(\.jpeg$)|(\.gif$)/i', $file) === 1) { ... }`

Comment: well you spoiled it for me. :)
thanks for the help, works like a charm.